# AnalyticsReceiver - what is that for? And why it causes 'Receiver does not require permission' warning?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver, google-analytics-sdk

In my Android application in manifest file i have following receiver and service declaration:

```
<receiver
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
   android:enabled="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false" />
```

To be honest it's quite old app and I don't remember why I've put that there. It was probably taken from Google Analytics docs. But now I can't find any up-to-date information about it.

What is more Android Studio shows me warning with that receiver:

> Receiver does not require permission
>
> Exported receivers (receivers
>   which either set exported=true or contain an intent-filter and do not
>   specify exported=false) should define a permission that an entity must
>   have in order to launch the receiver or bind to it. Without this, any
>   application can use this receiver.

Do I really need that receiver and service in my code? What is this responsible for? Is it still actual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Google Analytics, no, you do not need to manually specify the service and receiver in your manifest file.

[Here is the Google Analytics getting start guide for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). Note that if you are upgrading from a significantly older version, you may have additional work to perform elsewhere to upgrade. You should read through the entire guide to ensure that your app is still configured properly.

Comment: OK, thanks! I also looked at that page and didn't find anything related to those receiver and service so I thought it can be outdated. Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: This issue still remains. The Getting Started guide links to a page that specifies the config the posted in this question. It seems this config is used as a fallback for dispatching on non-Google Play devices.

Comment: As a follow up, adding tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver" to the receiver will remove the warning if Lint is becoming problematic for you.